# How to call a function on Tkinter class?(not inside label)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, function

I'm trying to use a function which a placed inside the class of Tkinder but the function(aktodec) can't be found and a get an error. I don't wanna call the def as a command of a button but as a function that will give value to one of my variables

```
from Tkinter import *
class ADialog:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        top = self.top = Toplevel(parent)
        Label(top, text="Number to convert").pack()
        self.numb = Entry(top)
        self.numb.pack(padx=15)
        Label(top, text="Base of incered number").pack()
        self.base = Entry(top) 
        self.base.pack(padx=15)
        Label(top, text="Base you want to be converted").pack()
        self.basemet=Entry(top)
        self.basemet.pack(padx=15)
        b = Button(top, text="OK", command=self.met)
        b.pack(pady=5)
    def aktodec(self,num,base): #####commands
        dec=0
        num=num[::-1]        
        for i in range(len(num)):
            s=int(num1[i])*(int(base)**i)
            dec=dec+s        
    def met(self):
        num=self.numb=str(self.numb.get())
        base=self.base =int(self.base.get())
        basemet=self.basemet=int(self.basemet.get())
        if base==basemet:
            Label(root,text="The number "+self.numb+"is converted to"+self.numb) ##why can't be print??
        if base==10:
            new=num    
        else:
            new1=self.aktodec(num,base)           ####why aktodec doesn't give value to "new"?? 
        Label(root,text="Number is"+str(new))       
        self.top.destroy()

root = Tk()
def open_dialog():
    dial = ADialog(root)
    root.wait_window(dial.top)

root.wm_geometry("400x300+20+40")
message=StringVar()
message.set("Complete the form")
Label(root, textvariable=message).pack(padx=30)
root.update()
message.set("Form completed")
Button(root, text="Done", command=root.destroy).pack()
Button(root, text="new", command=open_dialog).pack()
root.update()
root.mainloop()
```

And also I have a problem whith the label

```
Label(root,text="The number "+self.numb+"is converted to"+self.numb
```

which (i don't know why) won't appear to the root even the base=basemet. Help please(it's for a project in this week)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, a function can't modify some arguments(integers, strings) as perceived by the caller, they are immutable. However, some objects like lists are mutable.

```
def aktodec(self,num,base): 
    dec=0
    num=num[::-1]        
    for i in range(len(num)):
        s=int(num1[i])*(int(base)**i)
        dec=dec+s      
    return dec 
def met(self):
    num=self.numb=str(self.numb.get())
    base=self.base =int(self.base.get())
    basemet=self.basemet=int(self.basemet.get())
    new = num
    if base==basemet:
        Label(root,text="The number "+self.numb+"is converted to"+self.numb).pack()
    if base==10:
        new=num    
    else:
        new=self.aktodec(num,base)          
    Label(root,text="Number is"+str(new)).pack()      
    self.top.destroy()
```

Comment: So how i can run the function "aktodec" in tinter?

Comment: @user3216984 You used the function correctly, but the function need an extra return statement. check my code above.

Comment: thnx for the answer but if you can see by running the programe the label : Label(root,text="The number "+self.numb+"is converted to"+self.numb).pack() isn't printed even base==basemet

Comment: @user3216984 I can see the label if base=basemet

Comment: what do you mean you see the label..In the root?you give to the entry box of "Base of incurred number" and "Base you want to be converted" the same number and you see the label in the root?

Comment: @user3216984 Yes. The label appears below the buttons in the root.

Comment: you're right but it also give me an error: "Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/ada.py", line 33, in met
    Label(root,text="Number is"+str(new)).pack()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new' referenced before assignment" for my function

Comment: To avoid that error, initialize new in the begining of met function.

Comment: but i need "new" inside the else so it will be print if base<>10..Its like i can't call another function outside of a label(eg.Label(root,text="bla bla",command=self.aktodec(num,base)).Can i?